# Combing an If Statement with Pagination

Tags: pagination, forloop, loop

I'm trying to pull all the entries in a category that have a multi-selection selected and then paginate it.

If I just do the below, it works perfectly fine.

```
{% set entriesRed = craft.entries.section('eventRentals').relatedTo(category) %}
{% for entry in entriesRed if entry.rentalColor.contains('red') %}
            {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

But now I want to paginate it and I can't quite get the right syntax. To be clear, it's the top part I can't get a hold of, I'm modifying an already working existing pagination so I'm not including the bottom half.

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('eventRentals').relatedTo(category).limit(12).order('title') as entries if entry.rentalColor.contains('red') %}
{% for entry in entries %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
{# blah blah blah rest of the pagination ul li stuff #}
```

doesn't work, neither does

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('eventRentals').relatedTo(category).limit(12).order('title') as entries %}
{% for entry in entries if entry.rentalColor.contains('red') %}
     {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the pagination to work as expected, you need to incorporate the if into your `craft.entries` query. There may be a more elegant solution to do this, but looking at the database, the selected choices is saved as an array-like string:

```
["blue","red"]
```

This means that you can search for the value in the field like this:

```
craft.entries.section('eventRentals').rentalColor('*"red"*').relatedTo(category).limit(12).order('title')
```